# x3270 - automation script to login, send command and save into text file

Tags: python, php, websphere, 3270

i'm having difficult to write a script to access by using the x3270 emulator.

the machine is linux redhat.

I'd love to use php, do you have some example?

i have tried this, it opens the windows of x3270 but it seems stuck, i don't get how can i print in a txt file what i see on the screen.

```
<?php $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe","r"),
        1 => array("pipe","w"),
        2 => array("pipe","w")
       );

process = proc_open('/usr/local/bin/x3270', $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[0], 0);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0); 

function expecttxt ($thetxt) {
      global $pipes;
      $x = false;
      $g = false;
      while ($x == false) {
            sleep(1);
         while ($mydat = fgets($pipes[1])) {
                        if (preg_match("/$thetxt/i", $mydat)) {
                        $g = true;
                  }
                  if ($g == true) {
                        while ($mydat = fgets($pipes[1])) {
                        }
                        $x = true;
                        break 2;
                  }
         }
      fwrite($pipes[0], "ascii()\n");
      }
} 

if(is_resource($process)) {
      fwrite($pipes[0], "connect(L:hostname:port)\n");
      fwrite($pipes[0], "ascii()\n");
      expecttxt("CDN");
      fwrite($pipes[0], "string(session-name)\n");
      fwrite($pipes[0], "enter\n");
      fwrite($pipes[0], "ascii()\n");
      expecttxt("SESSION STATUS");
      fwrite($pipes[0], "PF(2)\n");
      fwrite($pipes[0], "ascii()\n");
      expecttxt("NEXT INFO");

      //...etc

}
```

thank you.

Comment: Another way to automate x3270 - which might be more in the spirit of PHP coding - is to enable the HTTP server. I added `-http 3270` To my startup command. (Available since 4.0, I think.) It listens on port 3270 if you use the above parameter value. Just pointing at `localhost` with that port - using a browser or eg curl - should get you started.